# If a magnetar's magnetic field can affect X-rays, can it affect visible light?

Tags: visible-light, magnetic-fields

Recently I've been reading about how a magnetar's magnetic field is so strong it can make the vacuum of space birefringent to X-rays, causing X-rays to bend.  I was wondering if visible light would be affected in the same way.  Would it be easier or harder to affect visible light photons like this?  Could a magnetic field actually be visible?

Comment: Do you have any references for this?  Is this in relation to pair production, for instance?

Comment: That's exactly how the effect works, is through pair production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, anything that can affect a photon in the X-ray spectrum can affect something in the visible spectrum. I found in the book "The Strongest Magnetic Fields in the Universe" by Beskin et al that one reason why this effect is so strong is because of "vacuum resonance", which occurs at plasma densities which depend on the square of the photon energy $E$. For X-ray energies (>1-2 keV), this density is right in the region of neutron star atmospheres. So, the effect is strongest for X-rays and much less strong for lower energy photons (like visible light).

"Could a magnetic field actually be visible"? We may need to be careful about what we mean by "visible", but from this perspective I think yes. If you can create a high magnetic field in a low density environment, you'll get this vacuum resonance from visible light.